# Scraping required fields exhausting a full website

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, web-scraping, lxml

I've written some script in python using lxml library which is capable of dealing with a webpage with complicatedly layed-out next page links. My scraper is able to parse all the next page links without going to the next page and hardcoding any number to the lastmost link and scrape the required fields flawlessly. Although I tried to do the whole thing specklessly, any improvement on this will be highly appreciable. Here is what I've tried with:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

main_link = "https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/"
base_link = "https://www.yify-torrent.org"

def get_links(item_link):
    response = requests.get(item_link).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    last_page = tree.cssselect('div.pager a:contains("Last")')[0].attrib["href"].split("/")[-2].replace('t-','')
    links = [item_link +"t-{0}/".format(page) for page in range(int(last_page) +1)]
    for link in links:
        process_docs(link)

def process_docs(nextpage_link):
    response = requests.get(nextpage_link).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    for items in tree.cssselect('div.mv'):
        name = items.cssselect('h3 a')[0].text
        try:
            genre = items.xpath('.//div[@class="mdif"]//li[b="Genre:"]/text()')[0] # I don't know If css selector could do this
        except IndexError:
            genre = ""

        try:
            imd = items.xpath('.//div[@class="mdif"]//li[b="Rating:"]/text()')[0] # Used xpath in lieu of css selector
        except IndexError:
            imd = ""

        print(name, genre, imd)

get_links(main_link)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite clean and understandable.

I would pinpoint only a couple of things:

- to avoid code repetition and to generalize getting search result properties, what if you would collect all the properties (genre, quality, size etc) into a dictionary:

  ```
  properties = {
      label.text: label.xpath("following-sibling::text()")[0]
      for label in items.xpath(".//div[@class="mdif"]//li/b")
  }
  ```

  As a bonus, you would not need the `try`/`except` part at all.
- as usual, you may [reuse a session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) to boost your HTTP requests part performance

Some other minor notes:

- it looks like that you make an extra request to the page number 0, adjust your range if this is the case
- `items` variable name is probably a bit misleading, at the very least it should be `item` since you are iterating over search result items one by one
- put `get_links()` call to under the `if __name__ == '__main__'` to avoid the code being executed if the module is ever imported
- I would also return or yield from the `get_links` and `process_docs` functions instead of printing things out

Comment: Thanks sir for the review and suggestions. You always lead me to the right direction but I get derailed while writing new stuffs. Btw, what could be the css selector for genre or imd? Thanks again sir, alecxe.

Comment: @SMth80 Thanks, sir! The actual genre or imd values are coming from text nodes and, from what I recall, you cannot match text nodes with CSS selectors directly. You may go into getting the `li` values and then parsing the `li` texts which would contain both the "label" and the "value" of a property - e.g. `Genre: drama` - then split by `:`..but, I think this is a good use case for XPaths.

Comment: @Sir alecxe, I've already created some css selectors to grab the "Genre" and "Rating" what I couldn't do in my above script. I thought you might like it that is why I drop here a link for you to look into what I did. https://www.dropbox.com/s/03iz95cxavp9gug/For%20codereview.txt?dl=0

Comment: @Shahin nice looking CSS selectors, good job, thanks.